# Binary search and insert to sorted array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement an insert object to a sorted array that uses binary search to find the correct index to put a new object.

You can see code at [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-binary-insert-q6hk2?file=/src/index.ts)

A have an array sorted with the next comparison method:

```js
interface Comparator<A> {
  (first: A, second: A): number;
}

function compareFields<A>(key: keyof A): Comparator<A> {
  return (a: A, b: A): number => {
    const first = a[key];
    const second = b[key];

    if (first < second) {
      return 1;
    } else if (first > second) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  };
}
```

To find index i use this `binarySearch` method

```js
function binarySearch<A>(
  source: A[],
  target: A,
  comparator: Comparator<A>,
): number {
  let first = 0;
  let last = source.length - 1;

  while (first <= last) {
    const middle = (first + last) >>> 1;
    const compareResult = comparator(source[middle], target);

    if (compareResult === 0) {
      return middle;
    } else if (compareResult > 0) {
      last = middle - 1;
    } else {
      first = middle + 1;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

And finally i try to find correct index and use `Array.spice` method to add new object to source array

```js
function binaryInsert<A extends any>(
  source: A[],
  target: A,
  comparator: Comparator<A>,
): A[] {
  const index = binarySearch(source, target, comparator);
  return source.splice(index, 0, target);
}
```

```js
const source = [
  { foo: 0 },
  { foo: 2 },
  { foo: 4 },
  { foo: 6 },
  { foo: 8 },
];
const expect = [
  { foo: 0 },
  { foo: 2 },
  { foo: 4 },
  { foo: 6 },
  { foo: 7 },
  { foo: 8 },
];
const target = { foo: 7 };
const result = binaryInsert(source, target, compareFields('foo'));

console.log({ expect, result });
```

As a result, I'm getting an empty array.
Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: `Array.splice()` affects the array itself.  It returns the elements that were removed, or an empty array if no elements are removed.  So since you aren't removing any elements, it is returning an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three errors in your code:

**Incorrect usage of Array.splice**

Check the [Array.splice docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> Return value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements.
>
> - If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
> - If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

**Incorrect implementation of binary search**

- what if you get first > last? You return -1 (incorrectly)

**Incorrect handling of negative index returned by binary search**

- you pass negative index to slice as start
- again, form docs (parameters: start):

> If negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array.

- you insert target item one position before the end
- but it happens to be right position in your test case. Test is green :)

Comment: What’s incorrect about returning -1 when first > last?

Comment: @Ry- binarySearch which returns -1 when the element is missing gives you no help when you try to insert a missing element into the right place. There is another flavor of binarySearch, which returns index if the element is found, but if it is not found, it returns position where the element should be added to keep the array sorted. (Note: this flavor requires extra check if the element at index returned is the one we were looking for).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. I was just confused as to why it was distinct from the one below it, then.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help. Your answer was very useful!
If someone is interested, they can find a working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-binary-insert-q6hk2?file=/src/index.ts) from the original message.